# Rejecting a Binary of iPhone App which status is "Waiting For Review" will cause anything?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have submitted a new version of my iPhone App and the status is **"Waiting For Review"**. 
I got some modifications done and want to upload a new binary for the same version.

- Can it be possible ?
- If I reject the binary, will it cause any other problem?
- Or I can simply reject the  related binary and upload a new one
  again?

Regards !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no harm. You can reject it and upload it again for review..

See screen from iTunesconnect guide: They have clearly mentioned this you can reject binary.

[image]

Comment: So, when I upload a new binary after rejecting the older one it will take same days to review again ?

Comment: Yes of course it will be in a queue again. Its like you were standing in a queue for a ticket and got out from queue and again decide to purchase you will have to join that queue again.. :-))

Comment: Thanks for the help !! This was my first time to reject a binary, so was a bit confused. :))

Comment: Yeah.. Better clear doubts before taking any actions. I made mistake once. What I did was app was rejected and I did not know how to resubmit and I deleted the whole app from account. So the bundle Id and App name both were gone for that iTunesConnect account.. :-D

Comment: Anytime happy to help..You should visit chat room. Ask questions there. You wont need to ask questions here. :-)) Will save a lot of time..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9766/discussion-between-anonymous-and-learner)